# Sql view combining columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two tables filled by a program. One contains an id, a name an 15 property names. The other refers to the id from table 1 and a property number and contains the value to each property for different items.
So table 1:

```
tab1_id | item_type | property_name_1| ... |property_name_15
```

table 2:

```
item_id | tab1_id | property_nr | value
```

I would like to create a view containing the properties for a specified item_type as colums:

view:

```
item_id |property_name_1 | ... | property_name_X 
...     |  value_1       | ... | value_x
```

And now to the additional problem:
There can be multiple entries in table 1 per item_type because there can be more than 15 properties per item type.
Of course there can also be less than 15 properties per item_type.

Based on the item type one would have to find out which property numbers are used, extract their names from table 1 and then fill the view with the values of that property number from table 2.

I know this could be easily done by writing an external tool but the preferred method would be to do this on the server in sql.

So two questions: Is that even possible to create something like that as a view or stored procedure in mssql?

And if yes could you point me to a way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a view - column names have to be fixed (I think!). Is a stored procedure acceptable?

Comment: Yes a stored procedure would also work. The restriction is to do it on the server. I'll edit.

Comment: I'm guessing you can't refactor the database at all?

Comment: Nope. But the people who wrote the program the database belongs to said they had reasons to design it that way. Which reasons they wouldn't tell...